# What file do I have to edit to make static DNS server in CentOS?

Tags: networking, centos, dns

Almost every distro I know will wipe `/etc/resolv.conf` on reboot (I think DHCP does this) and thus the place to add static DHCP entries varies per distro. How do I add static DNS servers to a CentOS server, so that I know that my entries will survive a reboot?

Comment: check out this question on SU http://superuser.com/questions/82337/slackware-change-dns-permanently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For CentOS it looks like you add `PEERDNS=no` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` (see [the documentation](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-dhcp-configuring-client.html)).

---

More generically, iIf you're using `dhclient` then put the following in your dhclient.conf file:

```
interface "eth0" {
 supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8;
}
```

For `dhcpcd` you add the `-R` option to the command line to stop it changing `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Finally `pump` uses the `-d` option on the command line to stop it changing `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

It would really just come down to how you configure your **[dhcp client](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-dhcp-configuring-client.html)**.

From the link provided, it seems the relevant file will be

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```